# parameters binding in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-connector

I have below python method which insert data in to a table. the first column is json_data and the 2nd column is file name. I am getting both the values to this function while calling this method from main.

def insert(sf_handler,data,file_name):

```
query = """INSERT INTO my_table (DATA,FILE_NAME)
           (select (PARSE_JSON('%s'),'%s'))""" % {json.dumps(data),file_name)}
pd.read_sql(query,sf_handler)
```

But while executing this i am getting below error. Can someone help on this.

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Just type cast the file name and remove the flower bracket with parenthesis it will work.

```
query = """INSERT INTO my_table (DATA,FILE_NAME)
           (select (PARSE_JSON('%s'),'%s'))""" % (json.dumps(data),str(file_name))
pd.read_sql(query,sf_handler)
```